# Динамически добавить поле в объект

Tags: javascript

Как добавить значение переменной в объект а не имя переменной?
Получаю `{"tempIndex":"hello"}` а хотелось бы `{"1":"hello"}`.

```js
var index = ["1","2"]
var names = ["hello","dude"]
var tempIndex = index[0]
var tempName = names[0]
var obj = {}
obj.tempIndex = tempName
document.write(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var index = ["1","2"]
var names = ["hello","dude"]
var tempIndex = index[0]
var tempName = names[0]
var obj = {}
obj[tempIndex] = tempName;

for(var item in obj){
document.write(item + " -- " + obj[item])
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Уже нашел в похожих вопросах)

Comment: Может подскажете как теперь через `foreach` получить поля имя:значение? А то `for(var element in obj)` возвращает только значение)

Comment: for(var item in obj){ var key = obj[item] }

Comment: Спасибо. Еще такой вариант нашел `for (var k in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        document.write("Key is " + k + ", value is " + obj[k]);
    }
}`

Comment: @BogdanShulga уже подправил ответ...))

Comment: Да как-то так и у меня получилось. Спасибо. Ваш вариант по приятней(компактней)